# Mysqli insert_id()

Tags: php, class, mysqli

I don't know, what's wrong in my code. I try to get the latest insert id, it's echoing 0. Any idea?

```
public function __construct() {
  $this->mysqli = new mysqli(MYSQLI_SERVER, MYSQLI_USER, MYSQLI_PWD, MYSQLI_DBNAME) or die ('Error with connecting to the database!');;
}
public function insert_id(){
   return $this->mysqli->insert_id;  
}

$db->query("INSERT INTO user(f_name, l_name) VALUES('$f_name', '$l_name')");
var_dump($db->insert_id()); // return 0?
```

Comment: Do you have a unique, auto-increment ID field?

Comment: PHP MANUAL:The ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query on success, 0 if the previous query does not generate an AUTO_INCREMENT value, or FALSE if no MySQL connection was established.

Comment: @Pekka: yes, id_user is the primary key.

Comment: After looking for hours for my mistake I found a lot of forums supposing, that the function is a bit buggy. For my insert statement it works pretty well, but using the update statement it's always returning 0...

Comment: Also, looks like you're missing closing quotes `"` in `'));`.  I'm not even sure how the var_dump is running if you were using the exact same code... in 2011.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use it as follow:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli(SQLI_SERVER, MYSQLI_USER, MYSQLI_PWD, MYSQLI_DBNAME);
if ($result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO user(f_name, l_name) VALUES('$f_name', '$l_name');")) {
   echo 'The ID is: '.$mysqli->insert_id;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

The mysqli_insert_id() function returns the ID generated by a query on a table with a column having the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute. If the last query wasn't an INSERT or UPDATE statement or if the modified table does not have a column with the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute, this function will return zero.

Looks like you don't have a field with AUTO_INCREMENT attribute or if you have one you are not using it in the query.